# Use Swagger generated from Azure Function in APIM Developer Portal

Tags: azure-functions, openapi, azure-api-management

I've created an Azure function and used OpenAPI decorations which expose through automatically added endpoints :

- /swagger/ui
- /swagger.{extension}
- /openapi/{version}.{extension}

I now imported my Azure function in APIM and was expecting that it would detect the endpoints and automatically take over the OpenAPI document.

Can you configure APIM to use the swagger from the Azure Function instead of manually having to edit/import it with each change?

Regards,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

APIM works in the following way-

1. If you will directly import the Function App as shown below then It will only import the operations which is there in the function code like GET or POST. Here it doesn't look for OpenAPI definition.

[image]

[image]

2. If you are linking the APIM instance in function app and have ticked Import Function option then it will create the operation based on the Swagger definition.
   You can check the definition invoking `https://{function_app_name}.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger.json` which is only having one operation **Run** in it.

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI Document on Azure Functions",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "host": "******.azurewebsites.net",
  "basePath": "/api",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/Function1": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "name"
        ],
        "operationId": "Run",
        "produces": [
          "text/plain"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "name",
            "description": "The **Name** parameter",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "The OK response",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So it will only show you **Run** as an operation in APIM.

[image]

[image]

3. If you will link the APIM while publishing your code to function app from visual studio then it will import GET, POST and Run operations.

[image]

So, if you want to use automatically generated endpoints in APIM then you need to add them explicitly as shown below-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated explanation. However we are in a 'special' situation where update/deployment is done via Devops, not via the UI. Looking for a way to either have APIM look at my swagger endpoint instead of using it's own OR able to update the swagger on APIM itself via powershell. It needs to be updated for each release